# MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed when inserting documents or finding documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I seem to be having an issue with my mongodb cluster, when I try to insert documents or find documents or really do any operation on the db I get this error in my node console

```
MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
    at processWaitQueue (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:591:46)
    at Topology.selectServer (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:323:9)
    at executeWithServerSelection (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:138:14)
    at C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:53:13
    at maybePromise (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:409:5)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:16:37)
    at FindCursor._initialize (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\find_cursor.js:54:50)
    at FindCursor.[kInit] (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:437:14)
    at next (C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:498:22)
    at C:\Users\luthe\Desktop\hydrofarm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:181:13 {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set {}
```

I've seen a few answers to these questions but they didn't fix my issue, here is my db connection setup below hoping someone can tell me what I'm missing, and yes I will move my password to an ENV variable later I'm just now setting the db up :) so I've covered it up for now

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const password = 'xxxxxxxxx';

export const storeData = async (data) =>{
   
const uri = `mongodb+srv://plantmaster:<${password}>@cluster0.yey8l.mongodb.net/plantstore?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
const newPLantData = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };

    client.connect(err => {
    const result = client.db("plantstore").collection("plantdata").insertOne(newPLantData, (err, res) =>{
        if(err) throw err;
 
    client.close();
    return result
})
    })
};


export const getData = async () =>{
   
    const uri = `mongodb+srv://plantmaster:<${password}>@cluster0.yey8l.mongodb.net/plantstore?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
    
        client.connect(err => {
            client.db("plantstore").collection("plantdata").findOne({lighting:"120"}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result.name);
                return result
                db.close();
              });
     
        client.close();
        })    
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by making the connection first and then running the query in an async pattern

```
   const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1
      });

        const newPLantData = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
        await client.db("plantstore").collection("plantdata").insertOne(newPLantData, (err, res) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result)
        })
```